# Как добавить дополнительный ряд в диаграмму excel из скрипта python, используя библиотеку win32com?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

Помогите, пожалуйста решить следующую проблему. Используя в python модуль win32com, можно построить диаграмму в MS Excel.

```
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import constants as c

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application') 
xl.Visible = True 
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add() 
ws = xl.ActiveSheet 

col_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
col_b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i in range(1, len(col_a) + 1):
    ws.Range('A' + str(i)).Value = col_a[i - 1] # set to A1:A5
    ws.Range('B' + str(i)).Value = col_b[i - 1] # set to B1:B5

ws.Shapes.AddChart().Select()
excel.ActiveChart.ChartType = c.xlLine
excel.ActiveChart.SetSourceData(Source=ws.Range("A1:A5"))
```

Вопрос такой: Как к построенному графику на диаграмме со значениями А1:А5 добавить еще один график со значениями В1:В5? То есть основная задача: построить два графика на одной диаграмме.